# SearchController filtering problem in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I've next model:

```
struct HashTags {
    var title = ""
    var tags = [String]()
}
```

and I try use UISearchController for seach text in tags array.

I impelemented UISearchController in my TableViewController:

```
class TagsController: UITableViewController {
    
    var hashtags = [HashTags]()
    var filtered = [HashTags]()
    
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    var searchBarIsEmpty: Bool {
        guard let text = searchController.searchBar.text else { return false }
        return text.isEmpty
    }
    
    var isFiltering: Bool {
        return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if isFiltering {
            return filtered.count
        }

        return hashtags.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if isFiltering {
            return filtered[section].title
        }

        return hashtags[section].title
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if isFiltering {
            return filtered[section].tags.count
        }
        return 1
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Tags", for: indexPath)
        
        var item = HashTags()

        if isFiltering {
            item = filtered[indexPath.section]
        } else {
            item = hashtags[indexPath.section]
        }


        let tags = item.tags
    
        cell.textLabel?.text = tags.joined(separator: ", ")

        return cell
    }

}

extension TagsController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
    
    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
        filtered = hashtags.filter({ (hashtag: HashTags) -> Bool in
            return hashtag.tags.contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
```

But it doesn't work as it should and when I start type text I receive blank screen. I need UISearchController work correctctly and search for text in HashTags tags arrays, showing correct number of sections and rows.

Comment: Before calling `tableView.reloadData()`, is `filtered` correct? Does it have all the you want?

Comment: It returns nothing. Just blank array.

Comment: Are you saying that `filtered = hashtags.filter({ (hashtag: HashTags) -> Bool in return hashtag.tags.contains(searchText.lowercased()) })` is wrong then?

Comment: I don't understad why it doens't work.

Comment: Ok, I understood. You are using `contains()` on an Array, so `tags` needs to contains the WHOLE `searchText.lowercased`, it's not if any of the value of the array contains `searchText.clowercased` Do you see the difference?

Comment: Yes. And how I should change my code to make it works correctly?

Comment: Take that sample to illustrate: `let array: [String] = ["he", "hel", "Hello"]; print(array.contains("h")); print(array.contains("he")); print(array.contains(where: { aString in return aString.contains("h") }))`

Comment: If you have a match, you want to show all the tags in the section? Because you have `return filtered[section].tags.count` at some point, and I don't think that's what you really want, you might want the same as when not filtering: `return 1`.

Comment: `hashTags.filter({ (hashtags: HashTags) in return hashtags.tags.contains(where: { (aTag: String) in aTag.contains(searchText.lowercased()) }) })` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. Now it works as it should!